# PHP Pear -- 'MDB2\Driver\mysql.php' missing

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, pear

I've inherited a huge project, and I'm having a real time just trying to get the damned thing on its legs. Every time I run the project, amongst all the `Strict Standards` and `Depreciated` notices is one error:

`Failed opening 'MDB2\Driver\mysql.php' for inclusion`

From what I've read, DBMS drivers stopped being included in default Pear installations over five years ago... So how I can fix this so that either it doesn't use `mysql.php` anymore, or that my Pear installation DOES have it?

According to the Pear website, I just need to type: `pear install MDB2_Driver_mysql` but I'm wondering if it wouldn't just be better to change the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it's just better to write everything from scratch. As a quock fix I'd still try to fimd that library and then partially replace all the smelly code. But that will be necromantic nightmare.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov If only the existing project wasn't so huge, and if only the budget for the changes wasn't so small! :(

Comment: Then you can only process step by step surmounting pain and sufferings. I know that feeling, I've been working for similar project for a year. So you just set error_reporting to exclude E_STRICT (to keep your mind healthy) and step by step refactor that carrion. Then, if the old architecture is still alive, you enable E_STRICT again and, if those errors still present, try to etch them too. Or you just end up crying in shower.

Answer (score 1):

You say the project is huge, so I would suggest you don't rewrite it to use a different DB access library as that could push out your release date quite a bit and instead just install the required MDB2 driver.

To install the mysql driver, just do:

```
# pear install --alldeps MDB2_Driver_mysql
```

(and maybe consider using the mysqli driver instead)

If you do decide to migrate the project to use a different library, I'd suggest [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) as it is one of the mature DB libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run PHP code written for an older version on a version of PHP that does not like some of the code.

Also see [this for some insight](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php) on what you actually have to have installed on the PC running wamp in order to actually access a DB2 database. Are you sure you have all of this installed before you try to install via PECL?

Comment: PECL? He didn't mention PECL, which is more for installing PHP extensions rather than packages of PHP code, and didn't mention accessing a DB2 database either. He needs to access MySQL via the MDB2 pear package.